# How can I use the results of a pattern match to produce a value in a match-expander?

Tags: scheme, pattern-matching, racket

In a `racket/match` pattern, I want to match some values, then create a struct that wraps them. For example, take the following (contrived) code:

```
(struct foo (a b c))

(define (foo-from-string str)
  (match str
    [(pregexp #px"^(.+)\\s(.+)\\s(.+)$" (list _ a b c))
     (foo a b c)]
    [_ #f]))
```

I frequently find myself matching this list of three elements in other patterns, then creating a struct from it. Therefore, I wanted to simplify this by writing a custom match expander. Ideally, it would work like this:

```
(struct foo (a b c))

(define (foo-from-str str)
  (match str
    [(foo-string value) value]
    [_ #f]))
```

That is, it should automatically match a string that satisfies the regex, then store the values into a `foo` struct on success and bind it to `value`. I tried writing something like the following to implement this:

```
(define-match-expander foo-string
  (λ (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ result)
       #'(and (pregexp #px"^(.+)\\s(.+)\\s(.+)$" (list _ a b c))
              (app (λ (v) (foo a b c)) result))])))
```

Unfortunately, this fails because `a`, `b`, and `c`, are unbound when the function passed to the `app` pattern gets called. Is there any way to implement such a match expander so that it can perform some arbitrary procedure on the matched values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `app` is exactly what you want here. You just need to do more in the `app`.

```
#lang racket

(struct foo (a b c) #:transparent)

(define-match-expander foo-string
  (λ (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ result)
       #'(app (λ (v) (apply (λ (_ a b c) (foo a b c))
                            (regexp-match #px"^(.+)\\s(.+)\\s(.+)$" v)))
              result)])))

(define (foo-from-str str)
  (match str
    [(foo-string value) value]
    [_ #f]))

(foo-from-str "1 2 3")
```

Answer (score 1):

First, there's a typo in your `pregexp` pattern:

```
(pregexp #px"^(.+)\\s(.+)\\s(.+)$" a b c)
```

I think you want:

```
(pregexp #px"^(.+)\\s(.+)\\s(.+)$" (list _ a b c))
```

As for your main goal:

> I frequently find myself matching this list of three elements in other patterns, then creating a struct from it. Therefore, I wanted to simplify this....

Well, you can accomplish this by using `app` with a suitable function. Interestingly, your `foo-from-string` function is... exactly that suitable function.

For example, to match on a string and get a `foo` struct:

```
(match "a b c"
  [(app foo-from-string x) x])
;;=> (foo "a" "b" "c")
```

Or to match on a string and get the `foo` fields, supply a `foo` struct pattern:

```
(match "a b c"
  [(app foo-from-string (foo a b c)) (list a b c)])
;;=> '("a" "b" "c")
```

---

Admittedly I'm not answering your question about match expanders, because I don't understand them well enough. So instead I'm suggesting maybe you don't need them?

---

Update: Actually that seems to be an answer to the match expander, too:

```
(define-match-expander foo-string
  (λ (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_ x)
       #'(app foo-from-string x)])))
```